# ChangePassword control does not work on unauthenticated user

Tags: c#, asp.net, login-control

Not sure what's misconfigured somewhere or whatever. An authenticated user can change his password, but for an unauthenticated user, clicking on the Change Password button does not do anything. No error is shown either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Stands to reason... I won't let you change a password till you prove who you are...

Comment: clarification: the user was redirected by clicking a link in the password retrieval mail. the user supplies his username and temp password.

Comment: @sjlewis: If the user supplies his username and temp password, is he then not authenticated? That's what the temp password is for, right?

Comment: He does not get authenticated even if he supplied the Username and Password in the Change Password page.

It seems weird because anything I put in just gets cleared, like the page is just being refreshed.

I tried placing breakpoints in the control's events but nothing is triggered.

The validators work, though.

Comment: I believe it is the code within the framework prevents that. As Oded said, it is an expected behavior. Even if I were the designer, I would choose this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A temporary fix is to redirect to the Login page with "returnUrl=ChangePassword.aspx". After getting logged in, user is redirected to ChangePassword.aspx and the change password control works.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Oded... But incase you still want to let unauthorised user change password... Check whether the Password change page is within the secured section in you Web.config file... Probably you might have given a blanket authorisation for all your pages only for authorised user... check you Authorisation Tag.. If so you can change the authorisation setting only for the password change page using location tag in you web.config file...

Comment: Nothing is set for this page. It's accessible by all.